# Hiding fields in the entity and adding computed columns

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table called Person with an attribute date of birth. My question is it possible and if yes how can I hide the date of birth column and instead to add a new attribute called age which is computed based on the date of birth.

Comment: What language / platform do you use? If you're using .NET, the `Browsable(false)` custom attribute can be used to hide the date of birth property. For the computed age, you can use a readonly property.